# Simple DatePicker-like Calendar

Tags: php, jquery, css

Can anyone recommend a simple datepicker calendar that I can use for a blog to link to different urls rather than for a form? jquery or css based would be good. When clicking next/prev month I don't want it reload page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jquery ui has a great datepicker
you can find it here

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

you can use

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect

to make your own actions when a date is picked

and if you want it to open without a form you could create a form that's hidden and then bind a click event to it like this

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(inputselector).datepicker('show');
});
```

Comment: Seconded; jQuery UI in general is great.  Would +1, but out of votes.

Comment: well it's the thought that counts ^^

Comment: Moral support is better than no support, I guess :)

Comment: I checked and it's tied to an input form. I wrote that I need to use for a blog to link to different urls rather than for a form, can this be done?

Comment: This is an awesome date time picker solution. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 5):

No need to include JQuery or any other third party library.

Specify your input date format in title tag.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js">
```

Body

```
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" alt="date" class="IP_calendar" title="d/m/Y">
```

Comment: That was a really simple and great solution. Thanks for this. I found it during a web search.

Answer (score 1):

I'm particularly fond of this date picker built for Mootools: http://electricprism.com/aeron/calendar/

It's lovely right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

How about the Dijit Calendar from the Dojo framework? It's pretty cool and very easy to implement. I always use this calendar.
https://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MooTools date picker

http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker
Example
http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker#examples

Answer (score 1):

[this datepicker](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php) is an excellent solution.  datepickers are a must if you want to avoid code injection.

Answer (score -1):

Use amsul datepicker Package. for step by step integration http://phpnotebook.com/index.php/95-laravel/109-how-to-integrate-datepicker-in-laravel-5

Answer (score -2):

[`jQuery datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) is good option