# ASP.NET Datepicker without calendar visualization

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker, web-controls, date

I'm working in C# / ASP.NET 3.5 and want to enable users to enter their date-of-birth. I've tried the asp:Calendar web control for this, and also considered using the jQuery-UI datepicker, and reviewed suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332379/simple-datepicker-like-calendar).

All those options don't seem to have the "mode" I want though. I do not want an actual calendar to pop up, but just a Day/Month/Year dropdown. My requirements:

- Just three dropdowns, for day/month/year
- Ability to set a min and max year
- Client side solution for helping pick a valid date (so don't allow 30 + February)
- Nice to have: culture based position switch for day/month and month/day

Can anyone suggest such a control? Or should I just move on and build it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeroen, there is no built in control.
The simple way to do this is add 3 drop down lists and add all months / years (Those are the simple ones).  Days change, so either you can statically add 31 and do some checking, or use a database that holds a bunch of dates and use that as the datasource.

Comment: Thanks JonH, you confirmed what I thought: just as well create the control myself

Answer (score 0):

I used a jQuery add in that handled this for me, I was able to update a hidden field that could be read from ASP.Net code behind, sorry I can't remember the exact plug-in but if you search on the jQuery site you should find it (I had a quick look but couldn't track it down, jQuery site search is pants).

Comment: Alas, I searched quite a bit but couldn't find it either :(. Tx for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's datepicker might be what you want:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/