# How do I get a calendar like in the pic attached in my webpage?

Tags: php, html

[image]

I am using PHP on client-side.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look [**here**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple DatePicker-like Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332379/simple-datepicker-like-calendar)

Comment: PHP is not client side. It runs at server.

Answer (score 1):

Usually datepickers are done with JavaScript, you cannot make dynamic stuff like select next/prev month using PHP only without page reloading on each action.

Here is good list of Javascript datepickers:
http://www.bitrepository.com/a-collection-of-free-javascript-date-pickers.html